# Como utilizar corretamente templates com jsf e primefaces

Tags: primefaces

Fiz um template e chameio-o dentro de outra página, mas o que eu aplico na segunda página não funciona. No index.xhtml eu escrevo uma frase para testar, mas não é impressa na tela. Só o template é renderizado.

Estou utilizando um projeto maven com primeface 6.0 e jsf 2.2.16.

//template.xhtml

xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

```
<h:head>  
<title>PROJETO MUSICANDO</title>  
</h:head>  

<h:body>  

</h:body>  
</html>  

//index.xhtml  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">  

<!-- importa o template -->  
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml"/>  

<!-- essa frase não aparece quando digito localhost:8080/webmusicos/faces/index.xhtml -->   
<h:outputText value="Bem-vindo ao projeto musicando"/>  


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O conteúdo na página index tem de estar dentro da tag composition.

//template.xhtml

xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

```
<h:head>  
<title>PROJETO MUSICANDO</title>  
</h:head>  

<h:body>  

</h:body>  
</html>  

//index.xhtml  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">  

<!-- importa o template -->  
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">  

<h:outputText value="Bem-vindo ao projeto musicando"/>  

</ui:composition>

</html>
```